# How to change the threshold of output of Keras model inside the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, predict

I am building a Keras model such that:

```
Y = 1 for X >= 0.5
Y = 0 for X < 0.5
```

My model:

```
def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.build(input_shape = (None, 1))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

    opt = SGD(learning_rate = 0.01, momentum = 0.99)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

After creating model I have set weights to [1] and bias to [-0.5]
Now, I am getting great accuracy, but getting wrong output for the following inputs:

```
[[0.50000006]
 [0.5       ]
 [0.50000001]
 [0.50000002]
 [0.50000007]
 [0.50000004]
 [0.50000001]
 [0.50000004]
 [0.50000004]
 [0.50000001]
 [0.50000003]
 [0.50000007]
 [0.50000008]
 [0.50000008]
 [0.50000004]
 [0.50000002]
 [0.50000006]
 [0.50000006]
 [0.5000001 ]
 [0.50000008]
 [0.50000002]
 [0.50000004]
 [0.50000006]
 [0.50000004]
 [0.5       ]
 [0.50000005]
 [0.50000003]
 [0.50000007]
 [0.50000004]
etc.
```

So, the model has learned that `Y = 1 for only X > 0.5` but I need `Y = 1 for X >= 0.5`.

**I know that this could be done by getting output by `pred = model.predict(X)` and then compare it manually. But I want this to be done inside the model. `model.predict_classes` should have a threshold. I want to change this threshold. How could I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`predict_classes` does not allow us to change the threshold. This is how keras implements it

```
def predict_classes(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=0):
    proba = self.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    if proba.shape[-1] > 1:
      return proba.argmax(axis=-1)
    else:
      return (proba > 0.5).astype('int32')
```

If you want to have your own threshold, then you will have to overload the method.

### Code

```
class MySequential(keras.models.Sequential):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MySequential, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def predict_classes(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=0):
    proba = self.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    return (proba >= 0.6).astype('int32')

def define_model():
    model = MySequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape=(None, 1)))

    opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.01, momentum = 0.99)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model

# Test

model = define_model()
x = np.random.randn(5)
print (model.predict(x))
print (model.predict_classes(x))
```